# It's possible create a app for Mac (desktop) using PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-desktop-app

I checked the documentation and I could not find a way to create a Mac App, it's that possible?

we can just build with phonegap mobile apps? not desktop apps? it's an another framework who do that?

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html

**UPDATE:** As of Cordova version 6.0, Mac OSX platform support has been added.

Comment: did you understand my question? i am not asking how to create a mobile app with phonegap, i am asking how to create a Mac app with phonegap.

Comment: It is possible by using cordova, but I haven't tried it yet. Look here for more informations: https://github.com/apache/cordova-osx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No phonegap cannot be used to build desktop apps. One of the main reasons devs use phonegap is to allow them to build web apps with the capability to interact with the phone hardware. This gives them  ability to write same web app built for different platforms (android, ios, windows phone etc).

Link below provides a list of target platforms that it supports

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_device_device.md.html

Update :
Google around and found : http://fluidapp.com/ (not free but cheap to buy) or https://macgapproject.github.io/ .. never tried either of those

Update 2:
Since 2016, PhoneGap/Cordova supports building apps for Mac. For more details, [see brianfit's response on the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32735730/its-possible-create-a-app-for-mac-desktop-using-phonegap/39435168#39435168)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dilberted , do you know any similar framework who does that?

Comment: Well if you are not looking to write a web app and port it to mac then mono could be your answer.

Comment: Google around and found : http://fluidapp.com/ (not free but cheap to buy) or https://macgapproject.github.io/ .. never tried either of those

Comment: You are totally wrong, cordova can be used on desktop apps too, windows 8-10 are fully supported, and there is a cordova-osx version too https://github.com/apache/cordova-osx

Comment: Op asked specifically for phonegap, for which the answer is no. Cordova-osx and phonegap are not the same. They have different features and address different set of requirements

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE: As of Cordova version 6.0, [Mac OSX platform support](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/osx/) has been added.

Comment: I edited the accepted answer and mentioned this post, as the current accepted answer is misleading. Hopefully the edit will get approved.

Answer (score 1):

PhoneGap currently supports:

- Apple iOS
- BlackBerry
- Google Android
- LG webOS
- Microsoft Windows Phone 7
- Microsoft Windows Phone 8
- Nokia Symbian OS
- Tizen
- Bada
- Firefox OS
- Ubuntu Touch

There is no Mac desktop in the list. PhoneGap is the mobile centric.

Comment: It is possible by using cordova, have a look at the cordova site under platforms: http://cordova.apache.org

Comment: yes, but phonegap is not focuesd on this, maybe you will add your comment as an answer - this could be useful fro the author and other people who got similar issue

Comment: No, phonegap isn't mobile centric, it supports window 8 and windows 10 apps, and you can build mac apps too with https://github.com/apache/cordova-osx

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Cordova project. I created a test prep app for my workplace that is currently working under the following platforms using a single codebase:

- Windows 8.1 and 10 desktop
- Mac OSX desktop
- iOS
- Android
- Windows phone

I'm pretty sure it would work with all other supported platforms but I don't have much use for Tizen ;)